# DHIS2 Map Embed/API error: "holes must not contain null elements"

Tags: dhis2, map

I need to embed a map from DHIS2 onto a web page. Dissecting the example @ https://play.dhis2.org/dem. I get to the map from its API link https://play.dhis2.org/demo/api/26/maps/ytkZY3ChM6J/data. But when I try the same in the local instance I get;

```
{"httpStatus":"Internal Server Error","httpStatusCode":500,"status":"ERROR","message":"holes must not contain null elements"}
```

Below is the stack trace from tomcat7-stderr.log. I would be grateful if someone can give a pointer to what I am doing wrong.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: holes must not contain null elements
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon.<init>(Polygon.java:143)
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory.createPolygon(GeometryFactory.java:405)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.GeoToolsPrimitiveFromJsonFactory.createPolygonFromJson(GeoToolsPrimitiveFromJsonFactory.java:137)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.GeoToolsPrimitiveFromJsonFactory.createMultiPolygonFromJson(GeoToolsPrimitiveFromJsonFactory.java:94)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.InternalMapObject.buildGeometryForOrganisationUnit(InternalMapObject.java:176)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.InternalMapLayer.addDataMapObject(InternalMapLayer.java:184)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.GeoToolsMapGenerationService.getSingleInternalMapLayer(GeoToolsMapGenerationService.java:284)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.GeoToolsMapGenerationService.generateMapImageForUser(GeoToolsMapGenerationService.java:140)
    at org.hisp.dhis.mapgeneration.GeoToolsMapGenerationService.generateMapImage(GeoToolsMapGenerationService.java:119)
    at org.hisp.dhis.webapi.controller.mapping.MapController.renderMapViewPng(MapController.java:292)
    at org.hisp.dhis.webapi.controller.mapping.MapController.getMapData(MapController.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that there is a problem with the coordinates representing a polygon associated with an organisation unit in your map. As the message indicates, there is a problem with the representation of a hole in the polygon.

To inspect your coordinate information you can export it in the raw DHIS 2 format:

```
/api/organisationUnits.json?fields=id,name,coordinates&level2
```

or as GeoJSON:

```
/api/organisationUnits.geojson?level=2
```

and then use a validator to identify the organisation unit with the invalid coordinates.